# Paw support for REST Level 3 (HATEOAS) Navigation? Following links

Tags: paw-app

I'm using Paw as a client to a REST Level 3 (HATEOS) API. As part of REST Level 3 links to related resources are discoverable as part of the response returned. Does Paw provide any REST Level 3 specific support such as making it easy to follow the links returned?

What I would really like to be able to follow those links by clicking (Command+clicking if needed) on the value URL in the response and it issue a GET against that URL. I would also like any HTTP headers to be carried over to the URL so things such as authorization would not break.

(It may or may not want to be smart and only do this if it's the same domain/context-root the original request so likely to be a REST Level 3 link and not any generic link).

See example of what would be great to be clickable below:

[image: Example Rest Level 3 (HATEOS) link to follow]

Ideally it would also be great to be able to navigate back to previous responses once the result has been followed. A lot of REST Level 3 links provide back or 'rev' links to allow this, but not all links are bi-directional so being able to go back like in a browser would be great.

Currently my workaround is:

1. Triple-clicking on the value
2. Command+C
3. Navigate to address bar
4. Command+A
5. Command+V
6. Command+Enter

So it's doable today, but 6 actions rather than a single click action on a URL contained in the response is tedious when repeated a lot of times. Also to navigate back to a previous response when there isn't a 'rev' link is a frustrating experience.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for the long delay... you actually made a great point, we're thinking about a way to follow URL links from JSON responses for a while, and now that more and more APIs rely on hypermedia, it becomes a must. It will definitively be in the next version! Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Brilliant! That's great news, I'll keep an eye out for the next version. Great work guys, and thanks for the response.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Any more news on this request yet?

Comment: Yes! We're actually working on this now. (It will come along with a nicer JSON view.)